# PHP gettext shared server locale - another translation method?

Tags: php, internationalization, translation, locale, gettext

After some 3 hours trying to make gettext work I noticed it doesn't worked all this time because my system does not recognize `pt_BR` locale so I installed it (Ubuntu) (Also, I needed to use `pt_BR.utf8`) now I was thinking a bit and what is going to happen if my website has a translation not supported by current Host/Shared Host? Everything translated will be useless? or someone in here is going to answer:

> You need to contact they to install the locale you want

Too obvious huh... There are some another away to translate a website easy like gettext where is not going to be messed by `locales`?
(Use `locale -a` If you want to see your locales.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using gettext, and as long as you're using unicode, you could try some other approach - I use xml and a little library I wrote - you can try it out here:

http://flarework.com/static/i18n/?lang=jp

Parsing your gettext and converting to the XML format used by the library should be pretty straightforward. The benefit of using strings stored in XML is that it's much, much easier to update than compiled gettext, which depending on the scale of your project might work out well for you. It's also totally independent of any server settings, which makes life easier.